# Divergence of Product and Difference Methods in Mediation Analysis

Tags: logistic, mediation

I am working on a mediation analysis problem, where I have a continuous mediator and a binary outcome defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
E[M|x,c] = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2C
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
logit\left(\frac{P(Y=1|x,m,c)}{1 - P(Y=1|x,m,c)}\right) = \theta_0 + \theta_1X + \theta_2M + \theta_3C
\end{equation}

Furthermore, I can also regress the binary outcome against only $X$ and $C$, which will be necessary when calculating the indirect effect.

\begin{equation}
logit\left(\frac{P(Y=1|x,m,c)}{1 - P(Y=1|x,m,c)}\right) = \phi_0 + \phi_1X + \phi_3C
\end{equation}

I know that the product and difference methods will be approximately equal when the outcome is rare. However, the product and difference methods will not coincide when the outcome is common, as shown and explained by Valeri and VanderWeele (2013):

**"When there is no exposure–mediator interaction, the product method and difference method will be approximately equivalent when the outcome is rare; and both will then be approximately equal to the natural indirect effect when all the no confounding assumptions hold. The problem with dichotomous outcomes arises when the outcome is common and has to do with the fact that logistic regression uses the odds ratio, which is a measure that is noncollapsible.”**

Furthermore, I know that neither will be equal to the natural indirect effect, as explained by VanderWeele and Vansteelandt (2010):

**"If, however, the outcome is not rare or if the error term in regression model 6 is heteroscedastic or not normally distributed, then the 2 quantities $\beta_1*\theta_2$  and $\phi_11 - \theta_1$ need not be approximately equal. Furthermore, in that case, neither $\beta_1*\theta_2$ nor $\phi_1 - \theta_1$ may warrant an interpretation as an indirect effect."**

In situations with a common binary outcome, it is recommended to use a log-linear regression model (instead of a logistic regression model) or to use an approach based on counterfactuals, such as the natural effect models proposed by Lange et al. (2012).

My question: the literature says that the difference and product methods will *generally* yield different answers when a logistic regression model is used to analyze a common binary outcome. In that, case neither of the two methods provide a measure of the true indirect effect. However, what can we say if the difference and product methods are equal when we use a logistic regression model with a common binary outcome? In other words, does convergence of the product and difference methods imply that the answer is correct, or can the product and difference methods converge to a wrong answer with a common binary outcome?

**References**

Lange, T., Vansteelandt, S., and Bekaert, M. (2012). A Simple Unied Approach for
Estimating Natural Direct and Indirect Eects. American Journal of Epidemiology,
176(3):190-195.

Valeri, L. and Vanderweele, T. J. (2013). Mediation Analysis Allowing for Exposure
Mediator Interactions and Causal Interpretation : Theoretical Assumptions and
Implementation With SAS and SPSS Macros. Psychological Methods, 18(2):137-150.

VanderWeele, T. J. and Vansteelandt, S. (2010). Odds Ratios for Mediation Analysis for a Dichotomous Outcome. American Journal of Epidemiology, 172(12):1339-1248.